# Android dynamic table rows with Edit Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How to Create dynamic table rows with `EditText`, In which user can add more row by clicking on "Add More" button and remove row by clicking on remove button.

[image]

Comment: This looks like some html did you use webview or you work with native android UI ?

Comment: Native Android UI

Comment: Search for "Custom ListView" or "RecyclerView".

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement listview using arrayadapter. On add button you have to add a new row to your adapter and update your array adapter by calling notifyDataSetChanged() also update your listview. This is how you will achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use dynamic procedure to create new table row .

I use frameLayout .
This is example for creating new image (You must adapt to your project - about positions ) :

```
    TextView TEXTVIEW = new TextView(this);
        int ID_FOR_DINAMIC_TEXTVIEW = 10000 +  i ;
        TEXTVIEW.setId( ID_FOR_DINAMIC_TEXTVIEW );
        TEXTVIEW.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        TEXTVIEW.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
        TEXTVIEW.setText(content_);
        TEXTVIEW.setX(EKRAN.WIDTH() / 100 * 9);
        TEXTVIEW.setY(EKRAN.HEIGHT() / 10 + EKRAN.HEIGHT() / 100 * 4 * i);
        xml_layout.addView(TEXTVIEW);

       // Toast.makeText( context_ ,  "GOOD" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Bonus : 
Class for position :

```
// def : SCREEN EKRAN = new SCREEN(context_);

//##############################################
// SCREEN - EKRAN CLASS
//##############################################
public class SCREEN  {

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    Point size_ = new Point();
    int width;
    int height;

    SCREEN (Context CONTEXT_) {

        dm = CONTEXT_.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int densityDpi = dm.densityDpi;
        height = dm.heightPixels;
        width = dm.widthPixels;

    }

    public int WIDTH() {

        return width;

    }
    public int HEIGHT(){

        return height;

    }
    public int W( int PER_ ){

        return width/100*PER_;

    }
    public int H( int PER_   ){


        return height/100*PER_;

    }

    //////////////////
    //extras
    /////////////////
    public int GET_PIX_FROM_DP ( float DP_VALUE )
    {
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, DP_VALUE , dm );
    }

    public int GET_PIX_FROM_DP2 ( float DP_VALUE )
    {
        float res = DP_VALUE * ( dm.ydpi / 160f);
        return  (int) res;
    }



}
```